# Convert huge XYZ CSV to GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, csv, gdal-translate, xyz

I have a huge amount of data in the form of CSV containing UTM coordinates as `X` and `Y` and an elevation value as `Z` information. I need to convert these data into a DEM as GeoTIFF for further analysis. In this case, a huge amount means 16 m. lines, with one point in `X`, `Y` and `Z` per line. The points are equally distributed, therefore an interpolation is not needed; each point just needs to be converted into a raster cell.

The original data came without separator, with fixed column widths. I already figured out how to convert the file syntax to use a separator instead of fixed widths and eliminate all space characters, using the stream text editor *sed*. From here on, normally my workflow would be to import the data into ArcGIS by creating a feature class from the `X`, `Y` and `Z` data and as a second step, converting the point shapefile into a GeoTIFF, using the *Point to Raster* tool. However, the file I currently have is way too big for this process.

Instead of the above described workflow, I was looking for an efficient alternative and discovered GDAL. However, in `gdal_translate`, the closest supported format I can find in the supported filetype list, is ASCII grid but no comma separated XYZ. Another difficulty is, that I **have UTM coordinates**, while most examples seem to use decimal degree coordinates. However, I **need to stay within the UTM system** (or at least, my output GeoTIFF needs to be in a UTM coordinate system).

So I am looking for a way to **convert the CSV XYZ into a GeoTIFF, using GDAL**, but so far wasn't able to find examples dealing with this exact problem. I would be very happy for some hints or even code examples.

Comment: Why do you think the GDAL method would be more efficient than the Esri method?

Comment: The exact example of using a xyz-csv for a tiff is in the documentaion here: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html

Comment: What exactly is the question? Right now the answer is "yes, you can use GDAL to convert". :}

Comment: The question is how to apply the conversion. Matte's comment seems to provide the solution - I'll  try this.

Comment: Ok! Can you provide a minimal example case of data? Do you want an answer in GDAL or would other free tools (eg GMT) be ok as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960568/using-gdal-in-python-to-produce-tiff-files-from-csv-files

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this using GDAL, it directly supports [XYZ format](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html). It doesn't matter if your coordinates are UTM, gdal_translate will output in the same coordinate system.

So to convert to GeoTIFF is as simple as:

```
gdal_translate test.xyz test.tif
```

Look at the [GeoTIFF](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) doc for output options (such as compression) and the [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) doc for more usage info. In particular, you should specify what the coordinate system is with the `-a_srs` parameter.

> *-a_srs srs_def:*
>
> *Override the projection for the output file. The srs_def may be any of the usual GDAL/OGR forms, complete WKT, PROJ.4, EPSG:n or a file containing the WKT.*

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:12345 test.xyz test.tif
```

Comma/space separated and fixed column widths, with and without a header row are supported.

> *The supported column separators are space, comma, semicolon and tabulations.*

```
$ head -n 2 test_space.xyz 
x y z
146.360047076550984 -39.0631214488636616 0.627969205379486084

$ gdalinfo test_space.xyz
Driver: XYZ/ASCII Gridded XYZ
Files: test_space.xyz
Size is 84, 66
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (146.359922066953317,-39.062997159090934)
Pixel Size = (0.000250019195332,-0.000248579545455)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 146.3599221, -39.0629972) 
Lower Left  ( 146.3599221, -39.0794034) 
Upper Right ( 146.3809237, -39.0629972) 
Lower Right ( 146.3809237, -39.0794034) 
Center      ( 146.3704229, -39.0712003) 
Band 1 Block=84x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.336 Max=0.721 

$ head -n 2 test_commas.xyz 
x, y, z
146.360047076550984, -39.0631214488636616, 0.627969205379486084

$ gdalinfo test_commas.xyz
Driver: XYZ/ASCII Gridded XYZ
etc...

$ head -n 2 test_formatted.xyz
x                       y                       z
146.3600471            -39.06312145             0.627969205

$ gdalinfo test_formatted.xyz
Driver: XYZ/ASCII Gridded XYZ
etc...
```

The only ***gotchas*** I'm aware of are:

1. The opening of a big dataset can be slow as the driver must scan the whole file to determine the dataset size and spatial resolution; and
2. The file has to be sorted correctly (by Y, then X).

   > *Cells with same Y coordinates must be placed on consecutive lines. For a same Y coordinate value, the lines in the dataset must be organized by increasing X values. The value of the Y coordinate can increase or decrease however.*

   ```
   $ head -n 5 test.csv
   x,y,z
   146.3707979,-39.07778764,0.491866767
   146.3787985,-39.07157315,0.614820838
   146.3637974,-39.07132457,0.555555582
   146.3630473,-39.07579901,0.481217861

   $ gdalinfo test.csv
   ERROR 1: Ungridded dataset: At line 3, too many stepY values
   gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'test.csv'.

   $ tail -n +2 test.csv| sort -n -t ',' -k2 -k1 > test_sorted.xyz

   $ head -n 5 test_sorted.xyz 
   146.3600471,-39.07927912,0.606096148
   146.3602971,-39.07927912,0.603663027
   146.3605471,-39.07927912,0.603663027
   146.3607971,-39.07927912,0.589507282
   146.3610472,-39.07927912,0.581049323

   $ gdalinfo test_sorted.xyz
   Driver: XYZ/ASCII Gridded XYZ
   etc...
   ```

Comment: I would highly suggest assigning a CRS to the output to make clear what the coordinates are: `-a_srs EPSG:12345`

Comment: Good point @bugmenot

Comment: where do you run those commands?

Comment: In a terminal/command prompt

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I just followed the suggestions above and found out `gdal_translate` is rather slow: 1M lines in xyz format takes dozens of seconds to process - problematic if one needs to process thousands of files containing 1M lines each. Another problem (at least with my files): The
.tif's created by `gdal_translate` had switched coordinates

I have not tested alternatives but just written a Python script using pandas to read the files and rasterio (a gdal wrapper) to write the result. This scripts processes one file in less then 1 second and uses multi-processing for multiple files. A job of 100 files á 1M lines takes 17 seconds on good hardware instead of 50 minutes with a bash loop calling `gdal_translate`. Until now, the crs is hardcoded to ETRS89/UTM32N (`CRS='EPSG:25832'`), but can be changed to anything else.

Link to the script: https://gist.github.com/philippkraft/2da0ab4314dd334463fe0e04985bba32

Answer (score 2):

Open Data DGM200 of Germany:
https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/open-data/digitales-gelandemodell-gitterweite-200-m-dgm200.html

Download the xyz file:
https://daten.gdz.bkg.bund.de/produkte/dgm/dgm200/aktuell/dgm200.utm32s.xyzascii.zip

Convert xyz to GeoTIFF file:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs utm32s.prj dgm200_utm32s.xyz germanyDGM200.tif
```