# How to obtain TIFF file using data from CSV files

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, software-recommendations, land-cover

I have a set of CSV files containing lat-long values for certain land cover classes.

```
 Long Lat
 80.1 23.0
 80.2 23.1
 80.3 23.2
 80.4 23.3
 ...
```

From this point on, I need to generate a TIFF file which contains information present in the CSV files i.e. lat-long and subsequent land cover classes at those coordinates. I am new to GIS and have completely no idea on how to get started. Should I first convert the CSV files in some other format readable by some software? And which would be the best platform to do so?

Comment: If your CSV is sorted by lat then lon (or can be modified to be) then you can use GDAL to convert directly to tiff https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/227322/2856

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use QGIS software which can be downloaded from here: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html ; it is an open source GIS software.

After installing it, use the add delimited text tool and set your data according to the dialog box (check for more information from here: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#importing-a-delimited-text-file)

[image]

Once you have loaded the data, just click on Project --->Import/export ---> Export Map to Image.

If you want a nice looking map, after loading you data create a new Print Layout and add the map elements before saving it as an image. Check the following documentation for more details: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html