# Converting CSV to GeoTIFF in QGIS/GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal

I have a custom CSV file with the columns UTM easting, UTM northing, red, green, blue. The latter values represent a RGB color of the pixel value. Now I want to convert this CSV to a raster GeoTIFF. I've found that there is a import function in QGIS (Layer -> Add delimited text layer) where I can import the CSV as vector layer. How can I transform it to a raster GeoTIFF?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227246/convert-huge-xyz-csv-to-geotiff).The `gdal_translate` command line utility only converts one z value so you would have to do the process three times (one for each color) and then merge the bands together. If you are interested in a Python solution using `gdal` I can try to provide one. It would be also nice if you provided a small sample of your data as a table so people can test it out.

Comment: Solved it using your recommendation