# Creating raster from centroids of another raster using QGIS/GDAL

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, centroids

I have a raster that is input into a model which generates outputs in a CSV format (Lon, Lat, Z value). The Lon and Lat are the centroids of the original raster's pixels. I want to use these centroids to create a new raster containing the Z value that perfectly matches the pixel size/grid of the original. Looking for a way to do this with QGIS/GDAL.

Below is a screenshot of my two files, the centroids (green) and the original raster beneath it:

[image: centroids file on top of original raster]

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the QGIS [Translate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html?highlight=translate#translate-convert-format) processing tool or [`gdal_translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) as GDAL (and therefore QGIS) directly read rasters in [X,Y,Z format](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html).

Note, the file has to be sorted correctly (by Y, then X):

> Cells with same Y coordinates must be placed on consecutive lines. For a same Y coordinate value, the lines in the dataset must be organized by increasing X values. The value of the Y coordinate can increase or decrease however.

See also this answer: [Convert huge XYZ CSV to GeoTIFF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/227322/2856)